# Solving a LeetCode problem to find first and last index of target in array in O(log n)

Tags: java, runtime, big-o, binary-search

I have solved a [leet code question](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array/). The question asks:

Given an array of integers nums sorted in non-decreasing order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

If target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

### Example 1:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8

Output: [3,4]

### Example 2:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 6

Output: [-1,-1]

### Example 3:

Input: nums = [], target = 0

Output: [-1,-1]

### Constraints:

- 0 <= nums.length <= 105
- -109 <= nums[i] <= 109
- nums is a non-decreasing array.
- -109 <= target <= 109

This is my solution (using binary search), but I am not actually sure if this is O(log n) since the runtime of my answer is 6 ms.

```
    public static int[] returnIndices = new int[2];
    
    public int[] searchRange(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] resultArr = new int[2];

        if(nums.length == 0 && target == 0) {
            resultArr[0] = -1;
            resultArr[1] = -1;
            System.out.print(resultArr[0] + "," + resultArr[1]);
            return resultArr;
        }

        binarySearch(nums, target);
        resultArr = getIndexOf();

        System.out.print(resultArr[0] + "," + resultArr[1]);
        return resultArr;
    }
    
    public int[] getIndexOf() {
        return returnIndices;
    }

    public int[] setIndex(int index) {
        if(index == -1) {
            returnIndices[0] = -1;
            returnIndices[1] = -1;
        }
        else {
            int lastIndex = index + 1;
            returnIndices[0] = index;
            returnIndices[1] = lastIndex;
        }

        return returnIndices;
    }

    public int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = nums.length;
        int mid = 0;

        while(low <= high) {
            mid = low+high/2;

            if(nums[mid] == target) {
                setIndex(mid);
                return mid;
            }
            if(nums[mid] < target) {
                low = mid+1;
            }
            if(nums[mid] > target) {
                high = mid-1;
            }
         }

        setIndex(-1);
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Try it with input of various sizes and you'll see whether it is O(log n)

Comment: it can't be logn if theres duplicate. i will be n.

Answer (score 0):

My submission takes 0 ms, yours actually returns wrong result. The idea is that array is non-decreasing but contains duplicates, but despite of duplicates you still may use binary search: you just need to promote index found to the left and to the right using binary search again but with other boundaries.

```java
        while(low <= high) {
            // that is not correct
            // must be either (low + high)/2
            // or (low + high) >>> 2
            mid = low+high/2;

            if(nums[mid] == target) {
                setIndex(mid);
                // here you should not return
                // you need to save mid, and
                // depending on what boundary 
                // you are looking promote it
                // either to the left or to the right
                return mid;
            }
            if(nums[mid] < target) {
                low = mid+1;
            }
            if(nums[mid] > target) {
                high = mid-1;
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! Just have a question, what do you mean by promote left or right? Does this mean if I find the target and its duplicate is one index higher then I should use binary search again but this time passing the right side and all its values to the right of that target?